# DNS lookup from lynx failing to ncbi eutils using ISP DNS but ok with 8.8.8.8

Tags: dns, lynx

I have several utilities that use the  [NCBI Eutils server](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/)  via wget or lynx.
Recently, lynx started failing with a DNS error,

```
Looking up eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov
Making HTTPS connection to eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?tool=biotechmarchywka&email=marchywka@hotmail.com&db=pmc&retmax=1&usehistory=y&term=dog+hypothyroidim
```

Modification of /etc/resolv.conf fixes the problem.

```
 cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search gha.chartermi.net
```

lynx info is,

```
 lynx --version
Lynx Version 2.8.9dev.8 (21 Dec 2015)
libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, GNUTLS 3.4.9, ncurses 6.0.20160213(wide)
Built on linux-gnu.

Copyrights held by the Lynx Developers Group,
the University of Kansas, CERN, and other contributors.
Distributed under the GNU General Public License (Version 2).
See http://lynx.invisible-island.net/ and the online help for more information.
```

I'm not sure it is unique to lynx but that is the only app complaining
right now AFAICT.

My question is if this is a known problem and if an updated version may be
a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: No, obviously I can add 8.8.8.8 ( I just used sudo vi ) but the question is about known issues with lync or if anyone knows a common ISP DNS bug, I think I get this from 2 cable providers. Thanks.

Comment: So this seems to be an issue relating to whatever other DNS service you are running on the local machine.  The `/etc/resolv.conf` file says to use `127.0.1.1` as the default DNS server, which means some DNS service is running locally. The question then becomes: What is wrong with that service?